# Fetching contents with single quote from wordpress mysql DB not showing properly

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a custom build page in which I have fetched post title and post content from my Wordpress blog site. In the site it is showing fine but in the custom php page the special characters (`'`) is printing garbage.

This is how i have written the php block

```
$get_post_sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM nn_posts WHERE post_status='publish' and post_type = 'post' ORDER BY ID desc LIMIT 15");
     while($post_list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_post_sql)){
         echo $post_list['post_name']."<br>";
     }
```

How can i print it perfectly?

Comment: `'` is not a special character. If you mean something like `’` then you need to make sure you're using UTF-8 all the way through.

Comment: Why don't use `$wpdb`, `get_posts()` or `WP_Query`?